# Problem with new rake task, why is rspec getting triggered?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

I've written a rake task in lib/tasks in my rails 3 project and it seems to run fine, only I get the following error after it runs:

```
$ rake dictionary:import_italian

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load': no such file to load -- /home/fletch/Dropbox/bin/kp/dictionary:import_italian (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
from /usr/bin/rake:19
```

Can anybody tell me what is causing this?

**Update:**  After having another look I found out that it happens with the other built in rake tasks, though `rake spec` seems to work fine.

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /home/fletch/Dropbox/bin/kp)
==  AddIndexesToWords: migrating ==============================================
-- add_index(:words, :title)
   -> 0.1121s
-- add_index(:words, :language_id)
   -> 0.0869s
==  AddIndexesToWords: migrated (0.1992s) =====================================

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load': no such file to load -- /home/fletch/Dropbox/bin/kp/db:migrate (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
from /usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Show is the source of your rake task if you want us to have any chance at answering this.

Comment: Looks like it's happening with all rake tasks, except the likes of `rake spec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out it was in my rake task, I used the word `describe` instead of `desc` to give it a description.  Not sure why that effected all of my other rake tasks, though.